SQL Server For JSON returns object as a string
I have the following sql code:
SELECT 
definitions = JSON_QUERY('{"ID": "INT)", "ID": "VARCHAR(23)"}'),
data = 
(
    SELECT ID, ID_FOR_DISPLAY
    FROM (SELECT TOP 1 ID, dbo.A2F_0012_ReturnIDforDisplay(1) as ID_FOR_DISPLAY FROM RateReviewBaseTBL) v(ID, ID_FOR_DISPLAY)
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
)
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;

This came from an example I found which utilized the following:
https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=ce2d52e2-d1f7-4d9c-8d02-a7d6fc062b7d
I copied this structure almost exactly except for some reason my code returns the object in a string format:
{"definitions":{"ID": "INT)", "ID_FOR_DISPLAY": "VARCHAR(23)"},"data":"{\"ID\":128,\"ID_FOR_DISPLAY\":\"NM-00000001\"}"}

Its not clear why its making my object a string rather than the example which seems to show the object as an object with {} and no strings around it.
However, I want the results to show this:
{"definitions":{"ID": "INT)", "ID_FOR_DISPLAY": "VARCHAR(23)"},"data":{"ID":128,"ID_FOR_DISPLAY":"NM-00000001"}}


Include all the relevant information we need in the question. There's no sample data in your question, nor do we have the definition for your function A2F_0012_ReturnIDforDisplay, so we can't run your query.

I tried to include the one fiddle to show the exactly same formatted code in that example works. How could my data effect whether the node becomes a string or not if I follow the same syntax?

Without an [mre], I cannot comment on why your code does not work as you expect.

As a side note, as well, a TOP without an ORDER BY is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using TOP you need to ensure the query has a deterministic ORDER BY so that you get consistent and reliable results.

without_array_wrapper does this, you have to wrap it in JSON_QUERY

Yea the TOP is just an example to grab a random one right now. However, I added what I want the results to show in the question.

@siggemannen can you show your answer of where to put the JSON_QUERY? I think you are on to something.

Something like: select ..., JSON_QUERY((select ... json path,without_array_wrapper))...

Are you sure you want "data":{\"ID\":128....? Do you not want "data":{"ID":128...?

You are correct. I want it without the \ . I updated question. Sorry! I have spent so long trying to figure this out and my brain is fried by now. I am new to JSON via sql.

Then JSON_QUERY is what you're after.

Can you show it in a answer with my code and il test it out? I just tried to wrap it around my one select but I think I am using it incorrectly because it wouldnt compile.

As siggemannen notes just wrap your subquery in JSON_QUERY. This is the query from the fiddle, as I cannot run your query due to no sample data or definitions
SELECT JSON_QUERY('{"NAME": "VARCHAR(23)", "DESCRIPTION": "VARCHAR(23)"}') AS definitions,
       JSON_QUERY((SELECT NAME,
                          DESCRIPTION
                   FROM (SELECT TOP (1)
                                Name,
                                Description
                         FROM dbo.Product
                         ORDER BY <Expression(s)>) v(NAME, DESCRIPTION)
                  FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) AS data
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;

db<>fiddle

So json_query just makes sure the node remains a json object?

@IrishRedneck Yes JSON_QUERY with no path forces it to assume it's valid JSON and not escape it. You only need to do this if you have WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
